# Remapping Apple Keyboard with Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, keyboard

I like to use an apple wireless keyboard with my laptop that runs Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 2.6.13 64-bit with the 3.16.0-38-generic kernel. However, I would like to remap the fn, alt, command, control and eject buttons to match the usual PC keyboard layout.

I found instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apple_Keyboard#Swap_the_Alt_key_and_Command_key.28Meta.2FSuper.29) for doing this. They are written with Arch Linux in mind but I don't see why they wouldn't work for Mint. I am able to switch alt and command using their instructions, but to swap fn and control and remap eject, I am instructed to add [this patch](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/hid-apple-patched-git/). I have downloaded the git files, but when I attempt to run `make` in that directory (`/home/MYUSERNAME/hid-apple-patched-master`), I get the following error:

```
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-38-generic/include M=/home/MYUSERNAME/hid-apple-patched-master modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-38-generic/include'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-38-generic/include'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have reinstalled and pointed to what I believe to be the correct kernel headings as instructed in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40979/what-is-the-path-to-the-kernel-headers-so-i-can-install-vmware) but I have been unable solve this issue.

My questions are really: 1. How do I fix this and install this patch? 2. Will this patch work at all on my set up? 3. If not, is there an alternative?

Bonus would be a little explanation on what I am doing and not just instructions as I am a linux novice.